# How to assign Roles on join?

Tags: python, discord, roles

Trying to give a Member the Role |-Newbie-| on join.

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles,name = "|-Newbie-|")
    await member.add_roles(role)
```

Comment: What version of the API are you using

Comment: of which api? xD

Comment: @Jab I think they're using the rewrite

Comment: @Spruiid Whats the problem? Is it giving you an error? Or

Comment: @yungmaz13 No, its just not adding the role if a new member joins

Comment: The functions isn't getting called, broadcasted it multiple times now

Comment: Any ideas why it's not starting? (the function)

Comment: @Spruiid Have you tested it by including an output like `await member.send("Foo")`? Because my thoughts were that the string in the `name` parameter wasn't equivalent to the name of the role on your server

Comment: Your code seems fine I'd put a  print statement in the function to ensure it's getting called. Also the bot needs to have `Manage Roles` Permissions and be above the role being given in role hierarchy.

Comment: @Jab It's not getting called if someone joins for any reason.. :/

Comment: Do you have multiple `on_member_join`-events? Have you enabled Intents?

Comment: Only a single one @Dominik 
How does this thing with Intents work? - Sorry, I'm new to that.. 

Got enabled this -> Privileged Gateway Intents on https://discord.com/developers/applications

Comment: @Jab It's not getting called

Comment: This is how to enable Intents: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html (*You need the members Intent*)

Comment: intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

Added these two lines @Dominik 

I'm really a noob with bots since this is my first one so I have no clue if this will do the job 

- its not working yet.